# zf2 generating entity with doctrine ORM

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfdoctrine

I have Entity classes generated with Doctrine ORM, and ZF2.

I changed a table structure and I want to update an entity class, so I am trying to regenerate the entity class but it's not working.

I used the following code:

> vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Album\Entity\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/clear

I got the error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Property "status" in "Album\Entity\TestRun" was already declared, but it must be declared only once  
>   orm:convert-mapping [--filter="..."] [--force] [--from-database] [--extend[="..."]] [--num-spaces[="..."]] [--namespace[="..."]] to-type dest-path

I want to re-generate the entity class for a particular table

Comment: There should be no two foreign key for same column in table

Answer (score 0):

If you change the structure of your Entity file a simple
`\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force` will alter the table according to your Entity definition.

If you still want to recreate the table simple drop the table from your mysql and run the  update command. You may have some cache files left so clearing those might be a good Idea, too.

You can clear the complete cache like so:

```
\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:query 
\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:result
\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:clear-cache:metadata
```

Comment: He wants to update an entity class from changed db table, not the opposite direction, as you described.

Comment: That's probably possible but in my opinion bad practice. Structure changes should be done within the entity. Then updated trough the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above it might be a bad practice, but nevertheless I use the following commands to achieve the result you are asking about:

```
vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --filter='Evaluation' --namespace='MyModule\Entity\\' --force --from-database annotation ./module/MyModule/src/
```

and another command to generate getters and setters:

```
vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:generate-entities --filter='Evaluation' ./module/MyModule/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```