# How to create entity of one table in zend 2 Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Suppose I have 5 table in my database and I did some changes in one of the table or added one more table after creating entity.

In Symfony 2, this can be done with

> php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AdminKbasicBundle yml --em=mykitchenoptions --filter=underlyingassign

In Zend2, Code below creates entity of whole DB but I want to create entity of just one table.

> php doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Album\Entity\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/

How to use filter parameter in Zend 2 Doctrine 2?

This is what I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092309/zf2-generating-entity-with-doctrine-orm) link

> php doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --filter='Testtable' --namespace='Album\Entity\' --force --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/

It gives error `"No Metadata Classes to process."`

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through ZF2's CLI, so all your configuration and stuff are set up:

`php vendor/bin/zf2.php orm:*`

Comment: Thanks for response, cant find any such file at given location therefore gives error "Could not open input file: zf2.php"